# Access database on different server without using master-master/master-slave replication

Tags: php, mysql

Is there a way i can query a local database that is on a different server (having limited access to this .. ie.config files) from the server i am working on now ?

Comment: Why don't you just connect to the other server?

Comment: media is still uploaded to the old server for now, so i need to be able to sync it with the new db, both of them can't be accessed remotely

Comment: Right, so just maintain two connections for now. If you have access problems, you have access problems. Pull down a database backup and restore it if you have to.

Comment: Thanks for your response, im still a little new to this so bear with me, i may not be explaining too well, but i need to be able to query the old server db (no remote access) from the new server. I can connect to the new server but my stuff is still being migrated from the old db to the new.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by just specifying the host so it points to the remote server that hosts the database:

```
$con = mysqli_connect("CHANGE_TO_SERVER_IP","username","password","database_name") 
      or die("Error " . mysqli_error($link));
```

Just make sure the given mysql account has permissions to access the database from a remote server and not just from `localhost` and `127.0.0.1` which is usually the case for security reasong.

Comment: yeah, my main problem is not being able to access the db fro ma remote server, is there another way ?
Is there a way to query a database from another server without remote access to that server?

Comment: You "cant" as in you dont have access, or having problems? Do you have access to script on the remote server?